# how joomla monitor the articles hits?

Tags: joomla, counter

joomla saves the hits of each article in the table "jos_content" in the field "hits"

how do it detects that the current user didn't visit this article before it increases article hits??? i looked at "jos_session" "data" field but found nothing related???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joomla does not check that the user has already visited the article or not.

It just increment the number of hits, each time when article is viewed.

Comment: I am talking about Joomla 1.5

Comment: i didn't think so , but i checked it you are right. but i think this is not a good method please guide me to the best method

Comment: for this you need to maintain a separate table. Which contain the `user ids` and `article ids` visited by user.